# jQuery validate plugin and WordPress footer.php file

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, validation

hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me...

I'm making a WP theme with two forms in the footer.php file. These need to be validated with AJAX, and I'm using [this plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

When building the HTML template the forms worked fine, they are checked and then the results are fired off in an email to the user. However, not the theme is taking shape the forms only work on the home page, and no other pages. I cannot understand why! The jS is in the header.php file, and the forms in the footer.php file - so basically the same code runs on every page. I'm also running some other basic jQuery script, a google map and a coinslider plugin. I have taken all these other bits of jS out to try and find the problem, and nothing has worked so far. I am using 1.6.1.

This is the jQuery for the forms;

```
$('#commentForm').validate();
$('#commentFormTwo').validate();
```

and this is one of the forms (the other form just has a different id) ;

```
         <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="">

    <label for="cname" class="label">Name</label>
    <input id="cname" name="fs_name" class="required text" minlength="2" /><div class="clear"></div>

    <label for="cemail" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="cemail" name="fs_email" class="required email text" /><div class="clear"></div>

    <label for="cphone" class="label">Phone</label>
    <input id="cphone" name="fs_phone" class="required text" minlength="6" /><div class="clear"></div>

    <label for="ccomment" class="label">Enquiry</label>
    <textarea id="ccomment" name="fs_comment" class="required text"></textarea><div class="clear"></div>

    <input type="hidden" value="sent" name="footer_sales" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
```

Hopefully this is enough info to give you the idea.

Can anyone kindly offer an advice? My head hurts : \

Thanks, Dan.

Edit: here is the home page: http://tinyurl.com/3lepjqv - if you check the about us page you will see the validate does not work. Please ignore any messy coding, this is far from complete!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I'm getting a js error which leads to this piece of code `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);` it apears `document.getElementById("map")` is null which causes the google maps api to throw an error which probably causes validate to fail aswell

Comment: Oh and the validation seems to be working fine here IE9 and IE8

Comment: I had better look into this also, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing all the code output from WP after it renders the HTML, but that would be my start point, see what JS is being output on the page you're having problems with and see if there are any conflicts in particular pages.

On a hunch I would think that perhaps something on the pages you are having problems with is conflicting with the calls to the validate() function.

EDIT: OK i had another look and it seems like the link to your JS file is broken on your pages other than the root /property/ folder.
This is probably due to how you are linking to 'js/jquery.validate.js' as this will be a relative URL.

If you change your js file to an absolute path it should sort things out.

Hope it helps,

Doug

Comment: Edited to include more detail

Comment: What a blunder - thanks for spotting that! Seems working when tired is not always a good idea! Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, I've had similar on wordpress and my own custon .htaccess rules!